# How to order big list in tabulate form to avoid memery error?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, list

I have the input list `data` like below, for which I'd like to tabulate based on letters order, locating each value in correct column for each row. The code below it works, but when I have a big input list (a `data` list with more than 10K sublists and `letters` list has about 12 elements) I get `MemoryError`

```
import pandas as pd

letters = ['A','B','C']
data = [['C', 3], ['B', 5], ['A', 1], ['B', 4], ['C', 2], ['A', 3], ['C', 8], ['A',9],['B',5]]

out = []
while data:
    out.append([
        data.pop(0)[1] if data and data[0][0] == h else None
        for h in letters
    ]) 

df = pd.DataFrame(out, columns=letters)
```

**OUTPUT:**

[image]

Each row is built from element `[0][1]` of each sublist of `data`. If it is found the sequence `['A','x'], ['B','y'], ['C','z']`, then the row would be `['x','y','z']`. If the sublist is `['B','y']` or `['C','z']`, then the other values for the row should be `None`. Is like the input `data` list was like this one.

```
list2 = [
          ['A', ''], ['B', ''], ['C', 3 ],
          ['A', ''], ['B', 5 ], ['C', ''],
          ['A', 1 ], ['B', 4 ], ['C', 2 ],
          ['A', 3 ], ['B', ''], ['C', 8 ],
          ['A', 9 ], ['B', 5 ], ['C', '']
        ]
```

My attempt to avoid the `MemoryError` is create 3 loops like this, but since initially I don't know how many rows would have the `output` list in order to separate in 2 or 3 loops, to create 3 outputs list. I hope make sense. Thanks for any help.

```
a = []
b = []
c = []

n = len(data)//3

if data:
    for k in range(n):
        a.append([
            data.pop(0)[1] if data[0][0] == h else None
            for h in letters
        ])
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code fails on `MemoryError` because you are popping the first element of a list in a cycle, continuously shifting all elements left to fill the gap at the beginning.

Here is one possible implementation of your algorithm without the pop method, which should run much faster and without the memory overhead:

```py
letters = ['A','B','C']
data = [['C', 3], ['B', 5], ['A', 1], ['B', 4], ['C', 2], ['A', 3], ['C', 8], ['A',9],['B',5]]

out = [[None] * 3]
column = 0 # This variable holds last filled column
for elem in data:
    # Convert the letter to column
    this_column = ord(elem[0]) - ord('A')
    
    # Create new row when new column is less or equal to last column
    if this_column <= column:
        out.append([None] * 3)
    
    # Add new element to the list
    out[-1][this_column] = elem[1]

    # Set column for the next iteration
    column = this_column

df = pd.DataFrame(out, columns=letters)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help an time. It works for this sample, but actually the elements in list `letters` could be a word of several letters. In that case doesn't work to order the columns.

Comment: You can create a dictionary that maps the words into column numbers.